# Implementing UIPageViewController's logic as a subview to a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, subview

I have to implement a UIPageViewController as a subview to my UIViewController. The UIPageViewController has some logic and other ViewControllers inside. My question is how to connect these two pieces of code below.

So this is my main UIViewController code:

```
class MyMainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }   
}
```

and my UIPageViewController code, which implements an endless loop between ViewControllers that he contains (I copied the whole code, probably it wasn't necessary ):

```
class TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newColoredViewController("Green"),
                self.newColoredViewController("Red"),
                self.newColoredViewController("Blue")]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self

        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                direction: .Forward,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        }
    }

    private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)ViewController")
    }

}

extension TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return orderedViewControllers.last
        }
        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return orderedViewControllers.first
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return orderedViewControllers.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        firstViewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) else {
            return 0
        }

        return firstViewControllerIndex
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the storyboard where you layout `MyMainViewController` and `TutorialPageViewController`, you will need to add a container view to `MyMainViewController` and then use an `Embed` segue to embed `TutorialPageViewController`.

When `MyMainViewController` is shown, it will now automatically insert your tutorial view as well.

[image]
[image]