# Fragments and ViewPager in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, android-viewpager, uipageviewcontroller

I am transitioning from android to iOS and wondering is there a native way to create a page template consisting on a couple of UI elements and have it created N number of times programatically. In android this would be accomplished with a Fragment which is created in a ViewPager on every page change.

I know iOS has a UIPageViewController, but I cannot find a way to create it N time programmatically without using the storyboard.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with a Container View which segues to a UIPageViewConroller. [Visually illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601005/implementing-uipageviewcontrollers-logic-as-a-subview-to-a-uiviewcontroller-in)

[This was a helpful tutorial to get me started with UIPageViewControllerse](https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started)